# JavaScript eval() to parse JSON after sanitizing with regexes — is XSS possible?

Tags: xss, javascript, json

Is possible to bypass my regex and execute any JavaScript?

```
<script>      
  function json(a){

  if (/^\s*$/.test(a) ? 0 : /^[\],:{}\s\u2028\u2029]*$/.test(a.replace(/\\["\\\/bfnrtu]/g, "@").replace(/"[^"\\\n\r\u2028\u2029\x00-\x08\x0a-\x1f]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g, "]").replace(/(?:^|:|,)(?:[\s\u2028\u2029]*\[)+/g, ""))) 
    try{
         return eval("(" + a + ")")
    } catch (b) {}

    g(Error("Invalid JSON string: " + a))
  }

  json(window.name);    
</script>
```

Comment: I believe is impossible.

Comment: I hope this code isn't going into production.

Comment: Good to make sure you don't fall afoul of Schneier's law in other venues. Always remember that self-reference as to impossibilities of compromise are a bad indicator for elephant detection.

Answer (score 19):

My [immediate reaction to this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKI-tD0L18A) was not positive, for a few reasons.

1. Trying to use regex to parse complex language constructs [is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/978756). Regular expressions just aren't suitable for such constructs.
2. Security through blacklisting is a bad idea because you will always be, by definition, one step behind the attackers. You should use a [positive security model](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Positive_security_model).
3. There are a *huge* number of [XSS filter evasion techniques](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet) that can be used on top of standard vectors. You cannot possibly detect and block them all.
4. Javascript parsing of JSON via `eval()` is [considered a security vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Security_issues).
5. Modern browsers [have support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Native_encoding_and_decoding_in_browsers) for proper native JSON parsing, via `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()`.
6. If you have to support old browsers, there is a safe [JSON library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) you can use that does not use `eval()` for decoding.

All in all, your regex approach is over-engineered, insecure, misguided, and redundant. You're attempting to solve a problem that has already been solved. [Don't be a Dave.](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/880/the-memes-of-it-security/1132#1132) Use the proper JSON parsing functions and libraries available to you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This code is used on production in a very large company. I am a security researcher and I am trying to explain why this is insecure for them. But I still believe it's impossible to exploit, if not, how?

Comment: The lack of a practical exploit is a technicality - if someone discovers a heap spray bug in an application, they still call it a security vulnerability even if they don't have a practical exploit. Even if *we* can't find a way around the regex, it doesn't mean someone else won't. Notice that Brian's answer *already* got partway to some valid / useful JavaScript. A determined attacker will spend hours or even days trying to break this filter, whereas we're only giving it a cursory glance. If you're doing a test or review of the code, you need to count it as a vulnerability.

Answer (score 4):

this
`(true");alert(9);//"`

is very close to a valid javascript statement and will be accepted in your regex.

Be careful with your regex, someone can bypass it.

Comment: I tested this, and it seems it is rejected. Which browser did you test this with?